# Why has COVID-19 affected less people in India than in the USA?

Tags: united-states, india, covid-19, comparative-politics

Both countries have declared a lockdown. So what went wrong in the USA?

Why has COVID-19 affected less people in India that in the USA?

Comment: There is a similar question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52388/how-us-medicine-system-weak-response-to-covid-19-can-be-explained and there is no answer to it..

Comment: Since the numbers change from day to day, please give a bit of leading contrast in the form of numbers, *e.g.* "On such and such date Nation X had **n** cases per million people, an Nation Y had **3n** cases."

Comment: Frankly these compare country X with Y are a bit tiresome, especially when the question asks "why" instead of what different measures did they take; lockdowns are hardly the same everywhere despite the name. The US is not [shooting people in the streets](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/22978/10980). But technically, such "why" questions they are on-topic here, even if they often fall into the fallacy of assuming correlation implies causation, so I'm [rather reluctantly] voting to reopen.

Comment: The better kind of question, in terms of being a a better fit for this site is like https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50942/how-much-do-the-italian-and-chinese-covid-19-lock-down-measures-resemble-each-ot or https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/51215/can-the-chinese-or-s-korean-covid-approaches-be-implemented-in-the-us-or-europe They also show you that not all lockdowns are the same.

Comment: On the other hand, this question (on India vs US) could be considered a dupe of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/51038/why-do-western-countries-seem-to-be-less-efficient-than-asian-countries-in-fight in the broader sense.

Comment: @Fizz The problem is that any answer is going to be speculative. No one knows how many people are infected in India and no one can know how that number will change in the future.

Comment: @Yes, I largely agree, but the answer below is fairly factual. We can answer with "we know what we don't know, but this info we don't know can make a lot of difference". In fact I suspect we might get more questions like this in the near future, so it would help to have something to close them as dupes of... The answers about what we don't know are going to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

India is not testing much. You can go [here](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-testing) and play around with testing relative to the population of some countries. While the US has already a relatively low testing rate given with 25 daily tests per million people, the number of India is even smaller. If you don't test, you can't count infected people

[image: tests per million people]